# Angulars ng-switch

Tags: angularjs, if-statement

In my angularjs apps loop I try to validate some json fields and function of retrieved values show theme in a table row or ignore it. I have been reading about ngswitch but I do not know how to use it properly. Here is what I tried

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
<table>
<div ng-switch="product.display_res">{{product.display_res}}</div>
     <div ng-switch on="isExists(product)">
      <span ng-show="isExists(product)"> 
          <tr><th>Display</th> <td>{{product.display_res}}</td></tr></span>
      <span ng-show="!isExists(product)"></span>
     </div>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will understand ngIf better.

```
<div ng-switch on="product">
  <span ng-switch-when="Apple">Apple<span>
  <span ng-switch-when="Banana">Banana</span>
  <span ng-switch-default>Default</span>
</div>
// ngSwitch is eval base on expression == "something"
// if product == "Apple" then span Apple will render
// if product == "Banana" then span Apple will render
// you don't need ngShow to work with ngSwitch
// product is $scope.product in your controller


<span ng-if="isExists(product)">
// this will be render if function isExists(product) return true


<span ng-show="isExists(product)">
// ngShow will show the span if function isExists(product) return true
// the span is always render, so it is different from ngIf ngSwitch
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [angular API](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch) to see how it works.

If I understand correctly what you are tring to do here's a correct version.

**EDITED BASED ON COMMENT**

```
    <div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <table>
      <div ng-if="product.display_res && isExists(product)">{{product.display_res}}</div> <!-- Show if product.display_res have a value (exept false or null) and product exist -->
         <div>
              <tr><th>Display<th></tr>
              <tr><td>{{product.display_res}}</td></tr>
         </div>
       </div>
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback with your provided I still have the row projected. What I try if product.display_res is empty do not show the row

Comment: Maybe you could remove ng-switch and use `<div ng-if="product.display_res && isExists(product)">`